# How do i pass an observable value into an Angular Bootstrap component?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ng-bootstrap

Im trying to figure out how to pass Observable values into a child component:

Service:

```
  public get percent():Observable<number> {
    return this.percentSubject.asObservable();
  }
```

Child Component:

```
  <ngb-progressbar type="success" [value]="completion.percent | async" [animated]="true">{{ completion.percent | async }}%</ngb-progressbar>
```

The text value renders as expected. Sadly, [value] input is assigning the observable object instance itself to the progress bar, not the emitted value. As i cannot modify the child compont (ngb) - is there a way to expose the derived values *without* manually hooking up a .subscribe() handler in the parent component?

Comment: async will subscribe it get the data and unsubscribe it I think you should directly send observable as input and do async operation within component

Comment: Have you tried putting the expression into parenthesis? `[value]="(completion.percent | async)"`

Comment: @BabarBilal - as this is a component from https://ng-bootstrap.github.io - i do not have write access inside the child component

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/mU9kSib2gq0s3IELhRfV?p=preview

Comment: Is `{{ completion.percent | async }}` rendered as the expected percentage?

Answer (score 0):

send a BehaviorSubject, then call asObservable().

// A variant of Subject that requires an initial value and emits its current value whenever it is subscribed to.

process:

1. click Add -> add()
2. add() -> next(itemNew)
3. [item$]="item$" -> @Input() item$;
4. update view

---

add-title.component.ts

```
  template: `
    <button (click)="add()">Add</button>
    <app-show-title-list [items$]="items$.asObservable()"></app-show-title-list>
  `

  items$ = new BehaviorSubject<Item>(new Item(''));
  add() {
    const itemNew = new Item(Math.random().toString());
    this.items$.next(itemNew);
  }
```

show-title-list.component.ts

```
    @Input() items$;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.items$.subscribe(item => {
          // do some
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please update your answer a little bit, add some explanation that directly addresses the question i.e. "how do I pass an observable".